# AWS BeanStalk: Often restarts the service automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, servicestack

I have a super small C# .NET Framework web application that I run on AWS Beanstalk. It works fine, except for one peculiar thing:

AWS seems to restart the service with unregular interval. I can see this as I can see log prints that only happens on startup.

In this case I am using ServiceStack `AppHostBase`, which has a `Configure` method that should be executed only once, on startup. In this method, a log print is done, and this gets executed between every 15 min to 2 hours approximately, indicating that the service is restarted at those times:

[image]

No update of the build has been done at those times seen above.

The Beanstalk configuration looks like this:

[image]

I would like to know why it restarts and what I can do to stop it.

Comment: is there any crash logs in the application or is the behaviour same of startup function on the local system? also, I am wandering about health check on the instance https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html

Comment: No health checks (see above), and crashes should all be logged. In the case above, there is no activity at all (zero). No usage of any kind, but still restarts...